# Компиляция Си и выполнение в Sublime Text 3, Windows 10

Tags: c, windows, sublime-text

Я хочу компилировать .c файл в Sublime Text 3, в Windows 10, но при попытке вывода с помощью `printf` что-то вывести, ничего не получается, не выводится текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске файла из `Windows PowerShell` всё работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке запустить из командной строки всё также выводится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как выглядит моя сборка:

```
{
   "cmd": ["gcc", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
   "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
   "working_dir": "${file_path}",
   "selector": "source.c",
   "shell": true,
   "path": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\"
}
```

Изменил папку `Мои работы` на `my_projects`, но это тоже не помогло

Comment: А зачем Вы пишете "./" перед именем программы? Это же выньдовс... А в повершелле Вы хотя бы ".\" написали, что синтаксически правильно.

Comment: @Vladimir поправил вопрос

Comment: На en_SO есть [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24225743) на похожий вопрос. Там можно либо в настройках проекта, либо в [конфиге](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27935037) редактора добавить запуск программы после компиляции. Вы это хотите?

Comment: @Vladimir спасибо большое, тоже, как раз нашёл такой ответ [тут](https://vike.io/ru/191593/)

Comment: Когда добавляете комментарий под кнопкой "Комментировать" есть ссылка "справка" - нажмите, там все написано :-) .  Текст пишите в квадратных скобках, а сразу за этим пишите ссылку в круглых: `[пример](http://адрес-ссылки)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мою проблему решила такая сборка:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell" : true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]