# Судоку не больше 1 решения

Tags: c, алгоритм, битовые-операции

Как мне определить, что судоку имеет больше 1 решения? Функция `trycell` просто ищет первое попавшееся. Я хочу если судоку имеет больше одного решения, то выдавать ошибку, что неправильно заполнили судоку.
Мне придётся вызывать функцию после её правильной отработки ещё много раз?

```c
void    ft_putchar(char letter)
{
    write(1, &letter, 1);
}

void    ft_putstr(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        ft_putchar(str[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

int     length_itr(int n)
{
    int out;

    out = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        n = n / 10;
        out++;
    }
    return (out);
}

void    ft_put_positive(int nb)
{
    if (nb != 0)
    {
        ft_put_positive(nb / 10);
        ft_putchar(nb % 10 + '0');
    }
}

void    ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    if (nb == 0)
    {
        ft_putchar('0');
    }
    else if (nb > 0)
    {
        ft_put_positive(nb);
    }
}

void    printf_d(int n, int space)
{
    int i;
    int length;

    length = length_itr(n);

    i = length;
    while (i < space)
    {
        ft_putchar(' ');
        i++;
    }
    ft_putnbr(n);
}

void    show(int *x)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (i++ < 9) {
        j = 0;
        while (j < 9)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                printf_d(*x++, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf_d(*x++, 2);
            }
            j++;
        }
        ft_putchar('\n');
    }
}

int     trycell(int *x, int pos)
{
    int row;
    int col;
    int i;
    int j;
    int used;

    row = pos / 9;
    col = pos % 9;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    used = 0;

    if (pos == 81)
    {
        return (1);
    }
    if (x[pos])
    {
        return (trycell(x, pos + 1));
    }


    while (i < 9)
    {
        used |= 1 << (x[i * 9 + col] - 1);
        i++;
    }

    while (j < 9)
    {
        used |= 1 << (x[row * 9 + j] - 1);
        j++;
    }

    row = row / 3 * 3;
    col = col / 3 * 3;
    i = row;
    while (i < row + 3)
    {
        j = col;
        while (j < col + 3)
        {
            used |= 1 << (x[i * 9 + j] - 1);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    x[pos] = 1;
    while (x[pos] <= 9)
    {
        if (!(used & 1) && trycell(x, pos + 1)) return 1;
        used >>= 1;
        x[pos]++;
    }

    x[pos] = 0;
    return 0;
}

void    solve(const char *s)
{
    int i;
    int x[81];

    while (i < 81)
    {
        if (s[i] >= '1' && s[i] <= '9')
        {
            x[i] = s[i] - '0';
        }
        else
        {
            x[i] = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (trycell(x, 0))
    {
        show(x);
    }
    else
    {
        ft_putstr("no solution");
    }
}

int     main(void)
{
  solve(  "........."
        "........."
        ".98....6."
        "8...6...3"
        "4..8.3..1"
        "7...2...6"
        ".6....28."
        "...419..5"
        "....8..79" );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Число решений судоку - с этим тоже знаком) Ностальгия)

Вообщем используй алгоритм решателя как отправную точку. И когда находишь решение, вместо того, чтобы выйти с результатом 1, запиши где-то в глобальном скопе solutions++.
Этого уже достаточно, чтобы посчитать решения. Но поскольку у нас другая цель, то сразу после инкремента проверяем: если solutions > 1, то throw new Exception, или как-то так. Ловить исключение лучше, думаю, аж перед всеми итераторами. Но можно и в самом итераторе ловить и пробрасывать ошибку.

Кстати, если совсем не хочется засорять глобальный скоп, то пускай trycell возвращает не 1 и 0 в случае удачи/неудачи, а число решений - 0 или больше.
В таком случае модифицировать код можно как-то так:

```
int     trycell(int *x, int pos)
{
    int row;
    int col;
    int i;
    int j;
    int used;
    int solutions = 0; // Счётчик решений

    row = pos / 9;
    col = pos % 9;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    used = 0;

    if (pos == 81)
    {
        return (1); // Найдено одно решение
    }
    if (x[pos])
    {
        // Не будем считать решения для ячеек-констант
        return (trycell(x, pos + 1));
    }


    while (i < 9)
    {
        used |= 1 << (x[i * 9 + col] - 1);
        i++;
    }

    while (j < 9)
    {
        used |= 1 << (x[row * 9 + j] - 1);
        j++;
    }

    row = row / 3 * 3;
    col = col / 3 * 3;
    i = row;
    while (i < row + 3)
    {
        j = col;
        while (j < col + 3)
        {
            used |= 1 << (x[i * 9 + j] - 1);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    x[pos] = 1;
    while (x[pos] <= 9)
    {
        // Вот тут будет основная модификация.
        /* if (!(used & 1) && trycell(x, pos + 1)) return 1;
        used >>= 1;
        x[pos]++; */

        if (!(used & 1)) {
            solutions += trycell(x, pos + 1))
            if (solutions > 1) throw new Exception() // Вот тут выбрасываем исключение
        }
        used >>= 1;
        x[pos]++;
    }

    x[pos] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Это не слишком экономно по памяти, всё таки на каждый рекурсивный вызов trycell будет создаваться свой отдельный счётчик решений. Но это должно работать (после отладки конечно же)

P.S. Код я не отлаживал, да и язык C не особо знаю, но надеюсь, что мой псевдо-код Вам понятен

Comment: Самое сложное для меня - это я не понимаю, как мне поставить по другому значения, чтобы найти новое решение, а не тоже

Comment: Найдя решение - продолжай итерацию не выходя из рекурсии решателя. Грубо говоря, считай не до первого найденного решения, а до конца, пока все итераторы не просчитают до девятки.

Comment: Это как поиск по файлу: "Найти" и "Найти далее". Когда ты только наченаешь искать первое решение, ты начинаешь с меньших цифр и перебираешь, пока не сможешь заполнить всё. Просто теперь не выходи, когда всё подставил, а продолжай подставлять.

Comment: P.S. Всех девяток точно не будет)

Comment: А вообще я бы предложил тебе переработать свой судоку так, чтобы он сам следил за своим полем и не позволял подставлять число, если такое же число уже присутствует в одной из инцидентных областей. Это позволило бы значительно упростить код решателя, тк о проверке значений беспокоится уже сама структура или класс Судоку.

Comment: Я не понимаю, могли бы написать, как это выглядит с этой функцией?

Comment: К сожалению я не супер-знаток С, да и отладить код мне не на чём. Однако могу через коментарии. Щас...

Comment: [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1079734/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%a1%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-sublime-text-3-windows-10), только нужно установить MinGw для GCC

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104212/discussion-between---and--).